# How to select as columns, a random set, from n-1 records for each record record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite new with MySQL, but I have a table named `Contacts`

with `ContactID` and `ContactName`

So let's say I have 100 `Contacts`. For each contact I want a random set of 3 from the `n-1` rest records but have this set of 3 as columns **in order to display a query of 100 records**  **with 3 columns of random Contacts**,

Is it possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: This does not display them as Columns

Comment: Means you want to display specific column records..?